# Java Swing Timer Countdown

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have to make a countdown program which also shows the tenths of a second;
for example from a 10.0 second countdown, it should display 9.9s, 9.8s, ... 0.0s

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        timer.start();
        timer2.start();

}                                        


Double timeLeft=5000; //5 seconds
Timer timer=new Timer(1,countDown);
Timer timer2=new Timer(1000,countDown2);
ActionListener countDown=new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        timeLeft--;
        SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss:S");
        jLabel1.setText(df.format(timeLeft));
        if(timeLeft<=0)
        {
            timer.stop();
        }
    }
};
```

what happens is it's taking more than 5 seconds to finish the 5 seconds.

I compared the code above with another Timer

```
int timeLeft2=5;

ActionListener countDown2=new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        timeLeft2--;

        jLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(timeLeft2));
        if(timeLeft2<=0)
        {
            time2.stop();
        }                  
    }
};
```

is it natural that they don't get the same?

Comment: Do you need to display milliseconds or deciseconds? I.e. 9.8s, 9.7s... or 9.899s, 9.898s...

Comment: 9.8, 9.7 will be good :D

Comment: Please include the line where you schedule countdown2 (and countdown too) on the timer. Are you executing them at the same interval?

Comment: updated :D Sorry for incomplete details

Comment: Do you mean timer.start() and timer2.start()? I meant the lines where you initialize the timers. e.g. timer = new Timer(100, countdown); timer2 = new Timer(1000, countdown);

Comment: ok :)) sorry edited it again

Comment: `Timer` will only guarantee that it will click at least ever `n` period, it's never exact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the label probably takes more that 1ms, which is why it can't keep up. If you only need to display tenths of a second, simply have your timer update less often.

```
ActionListener countDown=new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        timeLeft -= 100;
        SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss:S");
        jLabel1.setText(df.format(timeLeft));
        if(timeLeft<=0)
        {
            timer.stop();
        }
    }
};
Timer timer=new Timer(100, countdown);
```

Comment: oh.. I edited my post because I tried to use a normal timer with just seconds is it normal that one timer shows different result than the other timer? i.e timer1 is 5.5s while timer2 is still in 7s

Comment: ok i tried it with a stopwatch haha thanks it's synchronized with it

Comment: Just beware, this could drift (the time between ticks could be greater then the prescribed `100` milliseconds) based on the amount of time it's running and what might else be going on in the system (how busy the EDT is for example)

Answer (score 11):

The time between ticks (the time when `actionPerfomed` is called) is variable, it only guarantees that it will be at least `n` milliseconds

Instead of relying on some counter, which could become unreliable over time, you should try and calculate the difference between the time the `Timer` was started and the current time, for example...

[image: CountDown]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class CountDown {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CountDown();
    }

    public CountDown() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Timer timer;
        private long startTime = -1;
        private long duration = 5000;

        private JLabel label;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (startTime < 0) {
                        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }
                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long clockTime = now - startTime;
                    if (clockTime >= duration) {
                        clockTime = duration;
                        timer.stop();
                    }
                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss:SSS");
                    label.setText(df.format(duration - clockTime));
                }
            });
            timer.setInitialDelay(0);
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (!timer.isRunning()) {
                        startTime = -1;
                        timer.start();
                    }
                }
            });
            label = new JLabel("...");
            add(label);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```