# How to add a countdown code to a Java app?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, countdown

I've recently got a project in school.

- Create a Java GUI with an image as background and some textbox.
- the first textbox is just a text that says: Lunch break at 1pm.
- the second textbox is a countdown timer. This timer should appear 5 minutes before the end of the upcoming break, which counts down from 5:00 to 0:00 minutes every second. When reaching 0:00, the timer should respond to a text (e.g. "The
  Presentation will start shortly ").
- Image as a background: done
- Text that says: Lunch break at 1pm: done
- Countdown: I'm stuck at this point. I program a countdown timer first on the console. But I really don't know how to include this countdown to a Java GUI.

Do you have any suggestions?

This is my code for the background:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Bildhintergrund extends JFrame{


    
    //Background
        public Bildhintergrund () {
        setTitle(" Bildhintergrund");
        setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/path/to/bild.jpg")));
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JLabel background = new JLabel();
                add(background);
        
        //Text
    
        JLabel text = new JLabel() {
              public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                
              }
            };
        ;
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            Dimension size = text.getPreferredSize();
            getContentPane().add( text );
            text.setFont(text.getFont().deriveFont((float) 58));
            text.setText("Lunch break at 1pm");
            /*text.setAlignmentX(0);
            text.setAlignmentY(0);*/
            text.setBounds(300, 300, size.width, size.height);
            panel.add(text);
            panel.setLayout(null);
            add(text);
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Bildhintergrund();
}
        }
```

This is my code for the countdown:

```
  {
    /*int Time = 5;
    String time;
    int seconds;
    int minutes;*/
    
    int timet= Time * 60; // Convert to seconds
    long delay = timet * 1000;

    do
    {
      minutes = timet / 60;
      seconds = timet % 60;
      time = minutes + ":"  + seconds;
  
    
      System.out.println(GetTimer());
   
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      timet = timet - 1;
      delay = delay - 1000;

    }
    while (delay != 0);
    System.out.println("Another topic will follow");
  
  }
  public static  String GetTimer()
  {
    
      
    return  time;
  }
}
```

Comment: Step 1: You should almost never literally count down a timer. Instead, calculate and store the finish time, and on each tick/refresh calculate the time remaining.

Comment: 1) **Don't** tag the IDE. It has nothing to do with the problem at hand. (You'll know it;s relevant if getting different results from 2 IDE's from the same code.) 2) **Do** tag [tag:swing] as it is very relevant to the problem. 3) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Remove all the unnecessary cruft like backgrounds and the rest that has been successfully completed. Show only an attempt at implementing the countdown. 4) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is ..

Comment: .. intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 5) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: Thank you for your remarks! I'm new in Stack Overflow

Comment: Check out @MadProgrammer's answer in the question [Java Swing Timer Countdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337718/java-swing-timer-countdown)

Comment: *"Thank you for your remarks!"* You, who? Tip: Add @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `javax.swing.Timer` like this example:

```
javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000/*timer delay between calling ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) (in milliseconds)*/, new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Second over!!!");
                //put your code here
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(true);//makes timer repeats forever (or until call timer.stop() method)
        timer.start();
```